# Why is the text input field limited to 12 characters?

Tags: fields

I have run into the strangest "bug" with EE. I was running 2.5.2 and kept having any text input fields default to 12 characters instead of the normal 128. So I bit the bullet and upgraded to 2.5.5, hoping that would solve the problem. No luck. I just created a new text field, set the default character limit to 128, saved it and when I went back in it had gone back to 12 characters.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this was an issue with CartThrob. Do you have CartThrob installed. I recall troubleshooting the issue with someone on Twitter, @JasonTurcotte. It was a conflict with CartThrob, but I'm not certain if an official fix was released.

I've [linked to the conversation](https://twitter.com/JasonTurcotte/status/277105603581706240), so that you can contact Jason or CartThrob if you like. If CartThrob isn't installed, it's possibly a different conflict.

Comment: Now it all comes clear. Thanks for sharing this information. I do have CartThrob installed and I'll work around the limitation until he comes up with a fix. Thanks.